# How to speed up the creation of an image from points having a location (X, Y) and an intensity?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, opencv, optimization

I have table with columns: [X, Y, intensity] and want to generate an image from them. These tables can be large and this takes too much time right now. Therefore I am looking for ways to optimize the code.

The code uses pandas dataframes who look like this:

```py
import time
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Create demo version of the dataframes I use, which has similar characteristics as the real data
n = 27231221
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "X": np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=142.0, size=n), 
    "Y": np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=142.0, size=n), 
    "intensity": np.random.randint(low=0, high=60, size=n)
})
df.head()
```

```
    X           Y           intensity
0   63.643846   105.160795  11
1   123.693543  58.230852   55
2   2.289850    71.002206   42
3   132.666182  16.504936   7
4   99.317168   38.397257   56
```

The code itself is as follows:

```py
# Resolution of the image, must stay like this
x_resolution=5e-2,
y_resolution=5e-2

start = time.time()

# Create bins with a certain resolution for the 2D histogram of the points
x_min = df["X"].min()
x_max = df["X"].max()
x_range = x_max - x_min
x_edges = np.linspace(start=x_min, stop=x_max,
                      num=np.ceil(x_range / x_resolution))
y_min = df["Y"].min()
y_max = df["Y"].max()
y_range = y_max - y_min
y_edges = np.linspace(start=y_min, stop=y_max,
                      num=np.ceil(y_range / y_resolution))
bins = (x_edges, y_edges)

# Timing
end = time.time()
print('Created bins in:', end - start)
start = end

# Create an histogram with the average bin intensity
im_n, _, _ = np.histogram2d(x=df["X"], y=df["Y"], bins=bins)  # Number of points in each bin

# Timing
end = time.time()
print('Created hist, part A, in:', end - start)
start = end

im_n += 0.001  # Prevent division by zero is not possible
im_int, x, y = np.histogram2d(x=df["X"], y=df["Y"], bins=bins, weights=df["intensity"]) # Total intensity in each bin
im_mean = (im_int / im_n) # Average intensity in each bin

# Timing
end = time.time()
print('Created hist, part B, in:', end - start)
start = end

# From average intensity to normalized values suitable for displaying 
# Note, there are outlier values which must not be take into consideration, hence the max_intensity
max_intensity = df["intensity"].quantile(0.98)
im_mean = np.clip(a=im_mean, a_min=0, a_max=max_intensity) / max_intensity

# Timing
end = time.time()
print('Created image in:', end - start)
start = end

# Kernel sizes for smoothing the image
close_kernel_size=3
# Connect pixels close to each other using a square in the image
kernel = np.ones((close_kernel_size, close_kernel_size))
im_mean = cv2.morphologyEx(im_mean, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# Timing
end = time.time()
print('Smoothed image, part A, in:', end - start)
start = end

# Fill areas without high resolution pixels with lower resolution pixels
ellipse_kernel_size = 20
kernel = np.ones((ellipse_kernel_size, ellipse_kernel_size))
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(im_mean, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
idxs = im_mean == 0
im_mean[idxs] = closing[idxs]

# Timing
end = time.time()
print('Smoothed image, part B, in:', end - start)
start = end

# Show image
plt.figure(figsize=(3, 3))
plt.imshow(im_mean, cmap='gray')
```

And the output looks like this:

```
Created bins in: 0.7478666305541992
Created hist, part A, in: 15.96267056465149
Created hist, part B, in: 16.237517833709717
Created image in: 0.426699161529541
Smoothed image, part A, in: 0.056333065032958984
Smoothed image, part B, in: 0.17376041412353516

<matplotlib.image.AxesImage at 0x7f6945f99ac8>
```

So clearly most of the improvements could be achieved by improving the histogram creation. But I do not know if this is possible or how to do it..?

Besides adjusting the above code, if there are other (faster) ways to go from such a DataFrame to an image I would love to know them.

Comment: may not make a huge difference but you can explicitly call `.values` when accessing the dataframe columns: `np.histogram2d(x=df["X"].values, y=df["Y"].values .....` everywhere you access the columns append `.values`. This returns a np array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, so simply modifying your histogram code to this:

```
im_n, _, _ = np.histogram2d(x=df["X"].values, y=df["Y"].values, bins=bins)
```

improved the time from

```
Created hist, part A, in: 22.977999925613403
```

to this:

```
Created hist, part A, in: 6.108999967575073
```

So a near 3x improvement for both calls

I get similar times if I use `to_numpy()`:

```
np.histogram2d(x=df["X"].to_numpy(), y=df["Y"].to_numpy(), bins=bins)

Created hist, part A, in: 6.01200008392334
```

Comment: Ah that is incredible. Why is that the case do you suppose?

Comment: Well you return a np array as a view on the data, this is fully compatible with the `np` methods, otherwise you return a Series which then requires a call to `__array__` which may require copying/moving into a numpy array, so there are a few more hoops to jump through. I thought the performance wouldn't be much better but it seems it is just this simple change

Comment: Yeah it is incredible, on my machine I even see a speedup of 10X, from around 16s to 1.6s. This solves my problem of it being too slow.. Thanks a lot!